# Grant of patent US 5,095,151? Not OB listed?

Tags: expiration, us5095151

In reference to the patent: [US 5,095,151 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US5095151).

Is this patent granted? If yes, then when is the expiry of the patent or the market exclusivity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the patent was granted. It expired on March 10, 2009. It was subject to the pre-June 8, 1995 rules, which means that its term is at least 17 years after its issue date.